# Shell - one line query

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, freebsd

I need to execute a mysql query in one line using bash.

It should be something like this:

```
mysql database --user='root' --password='my-password' < query.file
```

But instead of the `< query.file` it would like to use a raw query like this:

```
mysql database --user='root' --password='my-password' < UPDATE `database` SET `field1` = '1' WHERE `id` = 1111;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: no, `<` use for indicate a file input in bash

Comment: On a side note: I'm a proponent of having that username & password either in a `.my.cnf` file or a custom one, using `--defaults-file=/path/to/file.cnf` Cleaner, reusable, etc.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Did you try

```
 mysql -u root -pmy_password -D DATABASENAME -e "UPDATE `database` SET `field1` = '1' WHERE `id` = 1111;" > output.txt
```

(the `> output.txt` part can be ignored but, it will be useful to see what was returned by the statement executed by looking at the file.)

Comment: The char ` made my command crash so I had to remove all of them. Worked fine after this.

Comment: From what I understand, the *space*    before `mysql` is also intentional, that is to make sure  no history was capture when this command is executed, be sure to copy the *space* as well

Answer (score 14):

Use the `-e` option:

```
$ mysql -e "UPDATE ..."
```

Comment: It should look like this? `mysql -e "MY_QUERY" --user=root --password=database-password` ?

Answer (score 6):

Use `echo` and a pipe:

```
echo "UPDATE `database` SET `field1` = '1' WHERE `id` = 1111;" | mysql database --user='root' --password='my-password'
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing your password in a command is generally a bad idea (people can read it over your shoulder, it probably gets stored in your shell history, etc.), but you can put your credentials in a file. Giving the file a name starting with `.` makes it hidden, which is also more secure.

```
# .db.conf
[client]
database=myDatabase
user=myUserName
password=myPassWord
```

Make sure only you can read the file:

```
chmod 600 .db.conf
```

Then call MySQL like so:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=.db.conf -e "UPDATE database SET field1 = '1' WHERE id = 1111;"
```

or:

```
echo "UPDATE database SET field1 = '1' WHERE id = 1111;" | mysql --defaults-extra-file=.db.conf
```

Note that `--defaults-extra-file` needs to be the first option supplied to `mysql` otherwise it freaks out.

Answer (score 1):

I normally prefer Triple less then as its syntax and approach is similar to file redirect. Easy to go back in history and modify query

```
mysql database --user='root' --password='my-password' <<< "UPDATE `database` SET `field1` = '1' WHERE `id` = 1111"
```

It is called Here Strings in bash. You can find more about them here http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html

It is useful when you want to pipe string to commands.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running this on a production environment, it would be better to login to the mysql shell first so as not to expose your db details.

Once logged into shell, why not just use a prepared.sql file?

> mysql -u user -p

Next, enter your user password

Now you are logged into shell and you can run commands securely from here:

mysql> use DBNAME
mysql> SOURCE file.sql

This is how I operate on the command line with my databases in order for my passwords not to appear in the logs.