# Sqlplus oracle : How can I run sql command on bash in 1 line?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Can I convert this into 1 command line on bash in sqlplus? cause i want to automate it.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
exit
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462416/shell-one-line-query/31545856#31545856?newreg=27ff13f929b544a5b5cd908766f30769 try the upvoted method

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You won't need the exit with automation because it should exit on end of file anyway. So on one line you could do:

```
echo 'EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);' | sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: Thanks. this would be the best answer as i don't want to create additional .sh or .sql at all

Comment: I try this command with select query but nothing happened. It just login and then disconnect. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a `;` or `/` (on a line of its own) to actually run the command. Just a guess, you'll need to provide more details for a better answer

Answer (score 6):

```
sqlplus user/password@host @file.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

you can wirite by follow in a shell

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
exit
EOF
```

or you can put this commond into a procedure

Answer (score 0):

`sqlplus /nolog @your_script.sql`

Comment: That won't work, since /nolog prevents SQL*Plus from logging on to the database.

Comment: Of course it won't - without putting the `connect` command into the script.