# How do I use ansibel-playbook to connect to mysql to execute SQL statements

Tags: ansible

I want to connect to mysql through ansible-playbook and execute SQL statements, but there is no relevant module in the official website of ansible. Does anyone know how to operate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there does not exist an official module to do something, you basically have two choices:

- Find a custom module that someone has written that will do it ([such as this one](https://github.com/zauberpony/ansible-mysql-query)).
- [Write a custom module that will do it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules.html).
- Do it using the [`command` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html#command-module) or [any of the other arbitrary command modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_commands_modules.html).

In your case, for a one-off playbook, I would typically go with the third option as I don't much care for running custom modules. I would make sure (Via Ansible of course) that `mysql` was installed on the box you were running against, and [build a `mysql` command line string based on what you need to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462416/shell-one-line-query) which you then run on a host with access to the DB server (or the DB server itself). That's the quickest and dirtiest method.